# Filter popup flickering in Ant design Table

Tags: css, reactjs, filter, antd

In below ant design table, For First "Name" Column filter functionality is added. But when I select any option like "Joe" and press "ok", then filter popup is kind of flickering before closing.

[image: filter popup]

Code link: https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-search-antd-4-23-6-forked-8bb1y3?file=/demo.tsx

Could anyone help and see how to fix this flickering issue.

Comment: I guess that flickering is caused by the lack of content under the table. when you filter something, the table height is shrunk and there is no space left for the filter popup so it kind of flickers

Comment: This is not because of any content under of table. If you observe the search field in filter, when you click on `OK` button, you'll notice there is small change in input field. (You can observe the placeholder of search field). You can create an issue in antd github.